# how to add links to footer in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this tag for My footer in bootstrap theme. I need add some links to under My usefull links. how can I do it

```
<footer>
      <p class="pull-right">Usefull links</p>
</footer>
```

this is not working properly

```
<footer>
    <p class="pull-right">Usefull links</p>
    <p>w3school.com</p>
    <p>universal</p>
    <p>privacy</p>
    <p>boomberg</p>
    <p>town</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: We cant help you without your css.

Comment: @PatrickMlr CSS is bootstrap css..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need add some links to under My usefull links. how can I do it

You need add a `<a>` tag with `href` attribute with value to your link.

```
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">w3school.com</a></p>
```

Also since you are using `pull-right` class on the `Usefull links` element. you must align the below tags to right as well. So I would recommend you to wrap everything in a `div` and give a class `pull-right` to the `div`

```
<footer>
 <div class="pull-right">
  <p>Usefull links</p>
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">w3school.com</a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.universal.com/">universal</a></p>
  <!-- similar to your other elements-->
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: ok your solution is working. can you give me hints how can change My footer color?

Comment: @Fernando you can add a CSS class rule with desired colors and apply that class to your footer..

Comment: @Fernando here you go with couple of snippets http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=footer .. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/1KEEq you can search for more in this site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add an 'anchor tag' i.e `<a>` to achieve what you are looking for.

For instance,

```
<footer>
  <p class="pull-right">Usefull links</p>
  <p><a href="#">w3school.com</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">universal</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">privacy</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">boomberg</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">town</a></p>
</footer>
```

You can read more on the same [**W3.org**](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)

Hope this helps.

***PS:*** '#' is a dummy link. You can replace it with the actual link that you want for the items.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain a valid reason for the downvote?

Comment: edited your answer for letting the down voter a chance to revert his vote.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <footer><a href="Your Link">Test</a></footer>
```